# Query by multiple meta elements not seeming to work - wordpress is timing out

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

Trying to run a query that pulls:

- get me 4 posts or pages that are not in sticky_posts and have `(my_featured_post = 1 AND photo-image_post_id > 0) OR (my_featured_post = 1 AND photo-image_page_id > 0)`
- OR if it's easier to do - somehow saying `(my_featured_post = 1) AND (photo-image_page_id>0 OR photo-image_post_id >0)`

I tried

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'my_featured_post', 
                'value' => '1', 
                'compare' => '='
            ), 
            array(
                'key' => 'photo-image_post_id', 
                'value' => '0', 
                'compare' => '>'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'my_featured_post', 
                'value' => '1', 
                'compare' => '='
            ), 
            array(
                'key' => 'photo-image_page_id', 
                'value' => '0', 
                'compare' => '>'
            ),
        ),
        'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page' ),
        'post__not_in' =>get_option('sticky_posts'),
        'posts_per_page'=> 4,        
   )
);
```

This does not seem to work. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do this in a single query - what you seem to need is multiple relationships between conditions, and as it works currently, meta_query doesn't let you do that. I googled it a bit and found others saying it doesn't, but I also went into the core code and looked at the WP_Meta_Query class. I can tell you definitively, you can't create multiple relations the way you need.

What I would suggest is to run a query that just grabs posts with `my_featured_post = 1`, as a meta query, and then get all the ids of those posts. Then run another query passing those ids to `post__in` - and running a meta query one for `photo-image_page_id>0 OR photo-image_post_id >0`